# In AWS S3 is it possible to add metadata to an object uploaded to a public bucket via POST?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

## what I'm trying

I intend to upload data to my bucket using POST. Currently I'm testing with a **public bucket** and can upload files this way

```sh
curl -X POST \
  http://s3.amazonaws.com/(bucket name) \
  -F 'key=${filename}' \
  -F file=@/myfile.jpeg
```

But I can't add "x-amz-meta-*", "Content-Type", "Content-Language" and other headers as specified in [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTForms.html). Neither am I able to add metadata to the files uploaded using POST via console. Here's what the console shows-
[image]

But I'm able to new upload files from console and add metadata. Is authentication the answer or what?

## tl;dr: how to accomplish this

```sh
curl -X POST \
  http://s3.amazonaws.com/(bucket name) \
  -F 'key=${filename}' \
  -F file=@/myfile.jpeg \
  -H 'x-amz-meta-lang: english' 
  # header not appearing
```

## note on headers

I tried passing them through -F instead but its not working

```sh
curl -X POST \
  http://s3.amazonaws.com/(bucket name) \
  -F 'key=${filename}' \
  -F file=@/myfile.jpeg \
  -F x-amz-meta-lang=english
```

Comment: Try to sent it as -F with your "key" value, that tutorial has it as form data?

Comment: Tried both, not working. Updates added in question.

Comment: can you try putting the file last in the field order, have your meta before the file. that document says: _The file or content must be the last field in the form._